How to read 800 millions of records efficiently in databricks?
I am working on databricks and trying to read 700-800 millions of records from delta table and without any transformation i want to ingest those record to 3rd party api using batch api.
I have pipeline running on airflow and there we are reading and ingesting data to api efficiently considering api’s throttleing limit. We are ingesting 130k records per second because 130 threads running in parallel and each thread is responsible to ingest 1000 events at one time to api. So that makes 130k per second and 6 million per minute. I want to meet same throttleing limit when i migrate my pipeline to databricks from airflow. Currently i am doing poc in databricks for same and i am facing challenges related to spill memory and disk, also jobs are in hanging state for long and i tried to optimize code as much as possible but same issue i am stuck at. On severless i am able to achive only 1.4 million per minute where i should expect 6 millions per minute. Looking for help here. Thanks
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder         
    appName("OptimizeBatchProcessing")•getOrCreate()
    source_table = "tableName"
    df=spark.read.format("delta").table(source_table)
    filtered_df=df.filter(df["day_type"].isNotNull())
    batch_size = 1000
    num partitions = (filtered_df.count() + batch_size - 1) // 
    batch_size
    partitioned_df=filtered_df.repartition(num_partitions)
    partitioned_df.foreachPartition(process_partition)


Please fix the indentation of your code. It would also be helpful to have a minimal reproducible example with a toy example and expected performance on it.

is this not related to h/ware / user (or a combination of) limits ?
